# ProDataObject as INPUT PARAMETER Java

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a table in Progress named `Car` . I need to have my progress code take an input parameter of one `Car` instance.

I've tried this

```
DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER i_tuPDO AS Car.
```

But this results in compiler error.

Comment: Tag `progress-4gl` instead of just `progress` otherwise no one will find your post.

Comment: I will do that in future, thanks for suggesting.

Comment: To be precise: nowadays Progress is the company, OpenEdge is the product (since 1998 or so). In the early ages there was such a thing as the Progress language, but they re-marketed that into OpenEdge. To make matters worse, the marketing department came up with the idea to call the 4GL "ABL" (Advanced Business Language).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a single record as input. You could either define an object that relates to the "car" record and input that object. Another option is to input the corresponding BUFFER-HANDLE instead.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt NO-UNDO 
    FIELD a AS CHARACTER.

CREATE tt.
ASSIGN tt.a = "HELLO".


RUN proc (INPUT BUFFER tt:HANDLE).

PROCEDURE proc:
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER phBuffer AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

    MESSAGE phBuffer:BUFFER-FIELD(1):BUFFER-VALUE VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

END.
```

If what you really want is inputting a DATASET into a procedure (or a program) that can be done like this:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt NO-UNDO 
    FIELD a AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE DATASET ds FOR tt.

CREATE tt.
ASSIGN tt.a = "HELLO".

RELEASE tt.

RUN proc (INPUT DATASET ds).

PROCEDURE proc:
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER DATASET FOR ds.

    FIND FIRST tt NO-ERROR.

    IF AVAILABLE tt THEN 
        DISPLAY tt.

END.
```

Comment: "You cannot use a single record as input.". That's not true. There's such a thing as a buffer parameter. (see the answer of @idspispopd).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you are trying to do. In case you want to pass a specific record of the table Car you could pass load the buffer and pass it or pass the rowid of the buffer. Example:

```
PROCEDURE test1 :

  define parameter buffer pbCar for Car.

END procedure.


PROCEDURE test2 :

  define input parameter rCar as rowid no-undo.
  define buffer bCar for Car.

  find bCar
    where rowid(bCar) = rCar
    no-lock.

END procedure.


find first Car no-lock.

run test1 ( buffer Car ).

run test2 ( rowid(Car) ).
```

Comment: Trying to input a specific record from Java to progress.

Comment: @sander: and how did you have the communication from Java to OpenEdge in mind?

Comment: Just wondering how you had the Java to OpenEdge communication in mind. Do you want to use the Java OpenClient/AppServer route?